# Any possibility to merge SSL client and server in one computer?

Tags: ssl, https, client-server

Im on the task on research project, where creating a full functional SSL (known as https when applying on the website) in one computer. Is it possible to combine SSL authentication and handshake in one computer? what i mean is the process of authenticate the client and handshaking are agreed in one application, or a LAN network.

My focus is i want to secure a existing website / webpage which already in internet, like this website, stackoverflow.com BUT i accessing it in https in my own network. The objective of asking of this because i want to show the higher education section that SSL can be achieved in terms of access a HTTP website and test with simple session hijacking to ensure its confidentiality and data integrity.

When succeed on this part, i will try apply another security feature which will slow the SSL hijacking being happen, for example one - time cookie or perhaps SessionLock?

==

*edit

Conclusively from my thought, SSL cannot be achieve if not having SSL server to host the webpage and SSL client to access to webpage. Merge SSL client and server are not ensure http are secure.

Comment: Madushan's reply didn't say any such thing as you have suggested in your edit.

Comment: What i know from his comment are SSL cannot be succeed in one computer, but with one server and one client accessing it. Sorry for indirect explanation. I re-edit back.

Comment: But that's not what he said. You are making it up. He said 'yes' twice. There is no way you can get 'cannot' out of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking...

If you're trying to load a page from a website hosted on your own machine, over SSL, yes you can do that.

If you have a custom client that wants to connect to a server over SSL and both the client and the server are on the same machine, yes you can do that too.

Comment: Im not detailing enough, sorry. There are webpage side, which the server or the webpage, and my own computer, which consist SSL client and SSL server. Basically https only happen when SSL server is on the server of the webpage, am i right? Im thinking of not touching the server of the webpage, but only make SSL authentication and handshake on my own computer. Is it possible?

Do you have any reference or the concept of what you mention on custom client that connect to server over SSL?

Comment: Sorry I still don't fully understand it...
You have a server somewhere that servers web pages. You're browsing to the page from your PC, using a web browser... Do you want to make that connection SSL ?

Comment: I didn't host any webpage on my server. And yes, i want to make a SSL connection and not with my own website but with existing website already in internet like a forum, a simple information website.

Comment: So, I'll explain what I understand again. You have a web server that serves pages using HTTP, no SSL, you want to make that SSL ? You cannot do that. SSL is a way of encryption. If you encrypt the traffic on one end, other party (the web server that serves pages) will not understand your requests because it doesn't know how to decrypt the traffic. If your intention  is to hide the traffic going out from your PC, then you can use a HTTPS Proxy server in the middle to communicate. Although traffic from your proxy to the actual server will not be encrypted.

Comment: So there is no way to serves SSL on existing HTTP webpage? Okay i get my answer for that. Thank you Madushan for the answer. Regarding your info with custom client, you have any reference for that? By create webpage on SSL server, can it be achieve within same network by using virtual OS?

Comment: Custom client part was actually a mis-understanding. I thought you want to connect to a SSL server with an existing client written in C#.

Comment: You can create a HTTP proxy which talks HTTPS to clients, but this sounds pointless in the extreme. Also it seems dangerous and/or deceptive to serve HTTPS which is not fully secure end-to-end.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, it's done all the time in test situations, which is about the only time it actually has a point.

But getting SSL working within a single host isn't going to prove much about whether 'SSL can be achieved'. Not that it needs any proving, as it's in use in zillions of Internet connections as we speak.

Comment: Yes. There are some testing that people try to secure their connection without the possibility of being eavesdrop. I take my best example by creating SSL on my own computer and secure the plain http website which already exist in Internet. Even https connection can be exploited using SSL hijacking, im thinking of making simple SSL connection over plaint http website on Internet, but it could not be achieve without client and server. Enhance security on SSL maybe will do once i successfully make a website which functional as https.

Comment: @HaziqOh None of that makes any sense. HTTPS is nothing but HTTP over SSL. If you think HTTPS is insecure it follows therefore that you must also think that SSL is as well.

Comment: That is what i meant to say, only i categorized HTTPS is HTTP with SSL and SSL is a protocol. Sorry i didn't highlight bout it.

Comment: @HaziqOh I do not understand. Please explain to me your enthusiasm for demonstrating the 'confidentiality and data integrity' of SSL when at the same time you think that 'HTTPS connection can be exploited using SSL hijacking'.